# installing pathos (python3) on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, python3, pip

I have tried the following command:

```
pip3 install pathos
```

and the error that I get is:

```
$ pip3 install pathos
Collecting pathos
Collecting pox>=0.2.3 (from pathos)
Collecting ppft>=1.6.4.7 (from pathos)
Collecting multiprocess>=0.70.5 (from pathos)
Collecting dill>=0.2.7 (from pathos)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.7.3 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from ppft>=1.6.4.7->pathos)
Installing collected packages: pox, ppft, dill, multiprocess, pathos
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joao/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/joao/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py",
 line 342, in run
prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/home/joao/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install **kwargs
  File "/home/joao/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py",
 line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)

  File "/home/joao/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py",
 line 1064, in move_wheel_files
isolated=self.isolated,

  File "/home/joao/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py",
 line 345, in move_wheel_files
clobber(source, lib_dir, True)

  File "/home/joao/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py",
 line 316, in clobber
ensure_dir(destdir)

  File "/home/joao/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py",
 line 83, in ensure_dir os.makedirs(path)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py",
 line 241, in makedirs mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13]
 Permissão negada: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pox'
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sudo pip3 install pathos`. It seems like a Permission Denied error.